# Testing Controller method that is not linked to any routes

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, web, testing

So I am giving a sample of my controller and web.php file.

```
controller
{
   public function add() 
   {
      //Method called via web.php
   }
   public function multiply() 
   {
      //how to access this while testing
   }
}
```

web.php

```
route::get('/add','controller@add');
```

And now I want to perform unit testing

case1: add `$response = $this->get(route('add'));` Now it will send a get request when `/add` is accessed and controller method `add` will be accessed. And then I can use various assertions to check its functionality.

case2: `multiply` Here there isn't any route specified, so it wont be able to access controller method.

How can I test my multiply method in such a case

***UPDATED ANSWER***

So from all the answers and comments, i have understood that in Laravel

1. Unit Testing -  Create a controller instance and then call the method that you want to test.
2. Feature testing - In this mode of testing, we will be calling the route and testing whether correct method has been hit and it is working as desired.

Thank You!!

Comment: Those don't look like unit tests to me. To unit test, you'd instantiate the controller you're wanting to test, and call the method you want to test.

Comment: Okay, I wasn't aware of that. Let me check. Thanks Anyway

Comment: FYI Testing via routes is usually referred to as a feature test. Laravel's default structure has a sample of this as well as a sample of a Unit test - https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/testing#introduction

Comment: @DarrylE.Clarke Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create the object of controller inside the test file like below.

```
 public function testBasicTest()
 {
    $object = (new UsersController());
    $response = $object->methodName();
    $this->assertTrue($response);
 }
```

Comment: I am getting correct resposnse, but i am getting when i am trying to assert using asertStatus(200). Error is rror: Call to undefined method Tests\Unit\templateTest::assertStatus()

Comment: Laravel provides a variety of custom assertion methods for your PHPUnit tests. These assertions may be accessed on the response that is returned from the json, get, post, put, and  delete test methods: From Laravel Official documentation

Comment: Can you sepcify which all assertions can be performed. assertTrue is working , assertStatus() and assertJson are not